# Large tile of WP 8.1 RT getting grayed out; smaller tiles appear fine

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app, written in Windows RT and XAML. The app suffers from an issue with one of its shortcut tiles placed on the home screen getting grayed out. In screenshot 1, the large tile is grayed out and the graying out is visible when compared with the tiles of other apps. In screenshot 2, the smaller tile appears perfectly fine.

The issue persists with only the large tile of the app, and it remains grayed out all the time, even when freshly installed onto a phone. I read a lot of reports about app tiles getting grayed out, and the reason behind them was some sort of backup being performed. But in my case the issue is permanent and exists ONLY with the large tile.

**Tile being grayed out:**
[image: Tile grayed out]

**Smaller tile appears fine:**
[image: Smaller tile appears fine]

How can I fix this issue? If the issue is because of some backup being performed in the background by the OS, how can I avoid this? Also, I did check the `backup` option in the `settings` menu, and it was turned off. So, theoretically, no backup could be performed, leaving no reason for graying out.

Any pointers?

**UPDATE:** Snippet from the manifest file where the tiles are set. The background color is set to `transparent`.

```
<m3:VisualElements DisplayName="my app" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="WindowsPhone" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="transparent" ToastCapable="true">
    <m3:LockScreen Notification="badgeAndTileText" BadgeLogo="Assets\LockImage.png" />
    <m3:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\WideLogo.png" Square71x71Logo="Assets\Square71x71Logo.png">
      <m3:ShowNameOnTiles>
        <m3:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo" />
        <m3:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo" />
      </m3:ShowNameOnTiles>
    </m3:DefaultTile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read somewhere that the tile can be grayed out by the system if our intentions are to write text on them, just to give it a better contrast.
Please try another tile template.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **image** you are setting when you create the *large tile*. Or maybe the **Background property**. I think its on this two properties. If not, please paste the code you are using to create this tile.

Comment: Added the code snippet; the background color is set to `transparent`. Also, the problem doesn't exist with the image as the same image worked fine in another test app; it grays out only in my application.